# IntelliJ Spring Web and Maven

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I am trying a create JEE spring web project (+spring security, mvc, web flow) and it will be a maven project with IntelliJ IDE.

I tried :

1) Create Project as "Spring",

2) Additional Libraries and frameworks : Spring, Spring MVC, Spring Security, Spring Web Flow. Web Application, Application Server, Hibernate.
And click on Finish button.

3) After project created, right clicked and "Add frameworks support" and selected maven.

I have three questions :

1) Is this a right approach to create a spring web maven project with IntelliJ?

2) Project has a lib folder that has spring, hibernate jars etc. They are not included in pom.xml file as dependency. How can i make them as they defined in pom.xml file so these jars will be in "External Libraries" folder?

3) When i didn't select "Application Server" while creating a new project, I cannot add later, when the project is created using "Add frameworks support". Why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a right approach to create a spring web maven project with
>   IntelliJ?

No, create a `Maven` (or `Gradle`) project form starting point and then add dependencies through `Maven` (or `Gradle`) dependency management system. Generally, managing dependencies through `lib` folders or `System Wide Dependencies` are **NOT** good ideas. [Read more on](http://12factor.net/dependencies)

> Project has a lib folder that has spring, hibernate jars etc. They are
>   not included in pom.xml file as dependency. How can i make them as
>   they defined in pom.xml file so these jars will be in "External
>   Libraries" folder?

Delete all jar files and replace them with dependency section of `pom.xml`. You should find `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version` coordiantes of each one. For example, for `spring-core` module, you should add this to your `<dependencies></dependencies>` section:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency
```

> When i didn't select "Application Server" while creating a new
>   project, I cannot add later, when the project is created using "Add
>   frameworks support". Why?

After creating project, you can add `Application Servers` or `Servlet Containers` through `Run > Edit Configuration` settings.